# Update query won't update, but doesn't show an error when run

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, utf-8

I'm currently working on a php user admin system for work. I'm able to create new users. I'm able to update the user account that I'm logged into--first name, last name, email, and password. I created a page that generates user’s information in a table. 
It shows user id, username, first name, last name, email address with a delete and edit link. The delete script works. The edit link goes to a form so I can update user info. The problem I'm having is: when I update the user’s information it's not updating it in the database. 
I can only update user’s information if I'm logged as that user. I'm using sessions, and I think it has something to do with my issues. Here's the code. This script is run after I press submit to update user information. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php

require("connect.php");

if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
header("Location: ../hound/login.php");
die("Redirecting to ../hound/login.php");
}

 $array_value = array(
    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
    ':first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
    ':last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
    ':id' => $_POST['id']
  );

  $query = "UPDATE users 
    SET 
    email = :email,
    first_name = :first_name, 
    last_name = :last_name
    WHERE
      id = :id";

  try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($array_value);
  }
 catch(PDOException $ex) {
 die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
 }
 header("Location: users.php");
 die("Redirecting to users.php");

 ?>
```

This is the form to edit user information. Once the submit button is pressed it runs the script above. Then returns to a page named users.

```
<?php

require("../scripts/common.php");


if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{

header("Location: ../hound/login.php");


die("Redirecting to ../hound/login.php");
}

$query_parm = array(

':id' => $_GET['id']

);


$query = "

SELECT
*
FROM users 
WHERE 
id = :id
";


try
{
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($query_parm);

 }
 catch (PDOException $ex)
 {

 die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

  }

 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


  ?>

 <form action="../scripts/edit_users.php" method="post">

  <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>

  Username:<br />
 <b><?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></b>
 <br /><br />
 First Name:<br />
 <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['first_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
 <br /><br />
 Last Name:<br />
 <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['last_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
 <br /><br />
  E-Mail Address:<br />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
   <br /><br />
   Password:<br />
   <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
   <br /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Update User" />
   <a href="../scripts/users.php">Back</a><br />
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `':id' => $_POST['id']` from where this is coming from? i cant see on your form or am i too sleepy?

Comment: I think Hendra Nucleo is correct. Your form does not supply 'id'   Adding that as a hidden input will likely make things work. Currently you are trying to update where id=NULL  .   While developing you might want to add print_r($_POST) to see exactly what your form is supplying

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your code, the update query is not able to get the  value of the `id` and hence not able to update the database. If your are trying to make an admin system that allows a user to update info about different users then you should pass the value of `id` in a hidden input field from the browser, else if a user is allowed only to update his/her profile details then you can retrieve user id from the session for example `':id' => $_SESSION["id"]` provided that you have stored the `id` information in the session when the user first logs in.

Comment: This is what did it for me. <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"> Thank you. I'm able to move on to the next step. Simple mistake.